# problem with adding right bar button to the navbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, rightbarbuttonitem

HI Everyone,

I have a navigation bar with a navigation controller. In one of my views, I want to add a custom right bar button item. I am trying to do so with the following code, but its not happening ! Can anyone kindly help me out ?

Thans.

Code:

```
////setup the top right save button
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(saveClicked)];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=saveButton;
[saveButton release
```

Comment: Where did you place this snippet?

Comment: @PengOne inside viewWillAppear function !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably call to navigationController in 2nd line is redundant, try to remove it:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
```